# Problem with rake db:migrate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake, rubygems, dbmigrate

When I try rake db:migrate, I get the following error:
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- mysql

And when I try to "gem install mysql"

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Can't find header files for ruby.
Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.

I checked the rubygems folder and mysql gem has been installed. Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: I'm on Fedora 10 . I tried yum install mysql-devel. But it said that is installed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sleepycat suggested, most probably you need the dev libraries for MySQL.

On Fedora / CentOS this should solve your problem:

```
yum install mysql-devel
gem install mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

This should sort it out on Ubuntu:

```
sudo aptitude install libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

Then install the gem again. You may need to delete the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 folder if it craps out.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The gem hasn't actually been installed.  You are missing either the ruby development files, mysql developer files, or linux build essentials.  Since you are asking, I'll assume you are on a linux distribution with a package manager; install the corresponding packages.